# Error when trying to add Apple SSO using the Apple provider to Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, apple-sign-in

I'm attempting to add Apple single sign on to my web application, powered by Laravel.

I'm utilizing the [javascript version of their sign in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js), which I'm not wedded to but seems like their preferred direction.

Following the instructions there, I've added the following to my log in page:

```
    <meta name="appleid-signin-client-id" content="com.mywebsite.service-id">
    <meta name="appleid-signin-scope" content="email name">
    <meta name="appleid-signin-redirect-uri" content="https://app.mywebsite.com/auth/apple/callback">
    <meta name="appleid-signin-state" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="appleid-signin-nonce" content="e3928c0c-edf0-11ed-a05b-madeupnonce">
    <meta name="appleid-signin-use-popup" content="true">
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
```

This code successfully creates an Apple login popup, and returns an AppleIDSignInOnSuccess event to the current page (not that callback page). The docs make it seem like this is expected, and I'm thinking the callback just isn't used here?

That event contains an authorization object with an id_token, code, and state. And at this point, I'm pretty lost!  I tried moving the user to the call back with that information.

```
        document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', (event) => {
            let detail = event.detail.authorization;
            window.location = '/auth/apple/callback?code=' + detail.code + 'id_token=' + detail.id_token + 'state=' + detail.state;
        });
```

That seems to pass through fine, but the Socialite Apple provider, upon calling Apple's endpoint, consistently returns:

> Client error: `POST https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` resulted in
> a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The code has expired or
> has been revoked."}

Here's my code processing the Apple callback:

```
public function handleAppleCallback()
{
    echo config('services.apple.client_id'); // com.mywebsite.service-id
    echo config('services.apple.client_secret'); // LongSecretFROMinstuctionsHERE
    echo config('services.apple.redirect_uri'); // https://app.mywebsite.com/auth/apple/callback
    $appleUser = Socialite::driver('apple')
        ->stateless()
        ->user();
```

The value for the key I obtained through instructions [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple), though I've also tried creating keys [on the fly](https://bannister.me/blog/generating-a-client-secret-for-sign-in-with-apple-on-each-request). I get the same results either way.  The configuration values I'm using in those instructions are:

```
team_id = '3Z8TYT4SL9' // my alpha numeric team id (not the real one)
client_id = 'com.sharewithleaf.service-id'
key_id = '85UX3UQVT8' // my alpha numeric key created linked to my primary app id (not the real one)
```

I think these are the correct values based on the instructions, but I haven't found documentation that shows examples of the resulting values to help me sanity check.

At this point I'm at an impasse. A few possibilities that I can think of:

1. I have the whole flow confused
2. I'm passing incorrect parameters to the callback after AppleIDSignInOnSuccess
3. I'm creating/using the wrong client_id and secret, and should be using something like an [API key](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api) instead.
4. I'm generating the key incorrectly, with the wrong values.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After all this, I figured out it was because I forgot the ampersands in my window.location URL :face_palm:

```
document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', (event) => {
   let detail = event.detail.authorization;
   window.location = '/auth/apple/callback?code=' + detail.code + 'id_token=' + detail.id_token + 'state=' + detail.state;
});
```

Should have been

```
document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', (event) => {
   let detail = event.detail.authorization;
   window.location = '/auth/apple/callback?code=' + detail.code + '&id_token=' + detail.id_token + '&state=' + detail.state;
});
```

Still, I'll leave this question up because it was difficult to find relevant documentation on this subject, so hopefully it helps someone else. Also, happy for comments on cleaning it up.